# Is it possible to only load a dictation topic while using Shared Recogniser and not with Inproc reconizer in sapi?

Tags: windows, speech-recognition, sapi

When I am using a shared recognizer to a previously registered  medical dictation topic , dictation grammar is loaded without error but when I change my recognizer to Inproc recognizer it is not able to load a dictation topic. Is there a way to load dictation topic while still using in proc recognizer?

My code for Loading grammar looks like

```
      CComPtr<ISpObjectToken>      cpObjectToken;
      CComPtr<ISpAudio>            cpAudio;
      CComPtr<ISpRecognizer> cpEngine;
      CComPtr<ISpRecoContext> cpRecoCtx;
      CComPtr<ISpRecoGrammar> cpGram;
      hr = cpEngine.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpInprocRecognizer);
      hr = SpGetDefaultTokenFromCategoryId(SPCAT_AUDIOIN, &cpObjectToken);
      hr = cpEngine->SetInput(cpObjectToken, TRUE);
      hr = SpCreateDefaultObjectFromCategoryId(SPCAT_AUDIOIN, &cpAudio);
      hr = cpEngine->SetInput(cpAudio, TRUE);
      hr = cpEngine->CreateRecoContext(&cpRecoCtx);
      hr = cpEngine->SetRecognizer(NULL);
      hr = cpRecoCtx->CreateGrammar(1, &cpGram);
      hr = cpGram->LoadDictation(L"Medical", SPLO_STATIC);
```

Comment: You should be able to use the topic from an inproc engine.  Can you show your code?

Comment: Inproc recognizers are "shells".  You need to specify the recognition engine and an input source.  It's likely that you're not actually binding a recognition engine before loading the dictation topic, which will fail.

Comment: I have added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inproc recognizers don't have a default SR engine, so calling

```
hr = cpEngine->SetRecognizer(NULL);
```

won't actually load an engine.  I wrote a simple function to load the default recognizer; the code's longish, so I won't put it inline, but you can find it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2010/03/01/specifying-parameters-for-an-inproc-recognizer.aspx).

Also, in your [other question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385847/how-to-register-dlm-and-ngr-files-generated-in-dictation-resource-kit-in-windo) you had the topic named "Medical", and here you have it named "Medicine"; they do need to be the same.